# Check if a value from a name sheet exist in a cell vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem of code conception.

I just coded something that look into a column (with 500+cells)
and if the value of a cell doesn't exist as a sheet name (in the same wb) then create the worksheet with the name of the value in that cell.

Here is my code :

```
' Si le ticker existe mais pas l'onglet,créé l'onglet
 LastRowData = Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'trouve la dernière ligne de Data
 LastColumnData = Data.Cells(1, Data.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'trouve la dernière colonne de Data

For i = 2 To LastRowData
    For Each sht In Perftitres.Worksheets
         If Not SheetExists(Data.Cells(i, 9), Perftitres) Then
         Worksheets.Add.Name = Data.Cells(i, 9)
         ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(2)
         End If
    Next sht
Next i
```

This code work. SheetExist is a function that say true if sheet exist and false if not.

Nevertheless, i want to do the inverse now :

If a worksheet as a name that isn't in the column then hide this sheet.
I can't figure it out ...
I want to look in every worksheet exept the first one (which is data).
If the name appear in the column, do nothing. If it's not then hide the sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, hide every sheet expect the first, then unhide the ones on your list? Or iterate through all the sheets, if it's name is on the list, unhide, else hide it.

Comment: The problem is that the list is not fix. I need a double loop ?

Comment: No, why would you? As a matter of fact, I don't see how your second loop does any good in your original code.

Comment: Side note, comments should say *why* not *what* - `LastRowData` and `LastColumnData` are very good identifiers already, their respective comments tell nothing that the variable names don't already say - I'd remove them. Also your code looks like it can use a peer review - feel free to come over and post your **working** code to [codereview.se] for help making your code more efficient and easier to read and maintain. (e.g. `Worksheets.Add` returns a worksheet reference, you should be using it instead of referring to `ActiveSheet` on the next line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but something like this:

```
Dim sName As String, m, sht As Worksheet

LastRowData = Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumnData = Data.Cells(1, Data.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Hide any unmatched sheets (and unhide any matched ones)
For Each sht In Perftitres.Worksheets
    m = Application.Match(sht.Name, Data.Cells(2, 9).Resize(LastRowData, 1), 0)
    sht.Visible = IIf(IsError(m), xlSheetHidden, xlSheetVisible)
Next sht

'add any missing sheets
For i = 2 To LastRowData
    sName = Data.Cells(i, 9).Value
    If Not SheetExists(sName, Perftitres) Then
        With Perftitres.Worksheets.Add(After:=Perftitres.Worksheets(2))
            .Name = sName
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It works but i don't want to hide the sheet Data. What is IIF ?

Comment: If you don't want to hide the "Data" sheet then you can check the sheet name before performing the Match lookup.  `IIf()` is a function - you can look it up but it works similarly to the worksheet `IF()`

Comment: I added : Data.Visible = True
Thank you.